# how to create RDLC report using multiple sql columns with same values to count in vb.net

Tags: sql-server-2008, rdlc, vb.net-2010

basically i m creating ***vb.net window application*** which can show the result in ***rdlc report...***

at the back end it is ***SQL server 2008.***

Is there any easy way to fill RDLC tablix based on row and column grouping.

The situation is as follows.

I have a table in SQL server like this

```
**Course       Adcat      sub1          sub2          sub3         sub4        sub5**

Ba1           Reg        HL           Hlit          His          PS          Env

Ba1           Reg        EL           Hlit          HS          Socio        Env

Ba1           Pri        HL           His           Hlit         HS          Env

Ba1           Reg        SL           Socio         Slit         PS          Env
```

This is just like a different course student registered in different categories and opted different subjects and it is stored in five columns as shown above.

I just want to see the report in RDLC like this

```
    **Course        subject        Reg                          Pri**          

      BA1            HL           1                              1

                     EL           1                              0

                     SL           1                              0

                     Hlit         2                              1

                     His          1                              2

                     PS           1                              1

                     HS           1                              0

                     Socio        2                              0
```

AND SO NO.

I just want to count the number of subjects from above mention five columns.

Please help me for this

i am using VB.NET window application and Sql server 2008.
Thanx in advance.

thank for response..
i have created a sql query and saved it as subsummary in view.
now how to call this from my vb.net application using button click.
a code i was used are:

```
Public Sub Show_SubjectSummary()
        sqlQRY = "SELECT * FROM tblstudetail where" _
             & "[session] = '2015' AND" _
             & "[course] = 'B.A. I' AND" _
            & "[ADstatus] LIKE 'OK'"
        ds = New DataSet
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQRY, Conn)
        da.Fill(ds, "tblstudetail")
        RDLCreportview.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = Application.StartupPath & "\Report\SubjectSummary.rdlc"
        sReportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1"
        sReportDataSource.Value = ds.Tables(0)
        RDLCreportview.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath & "\Report\SubjectSummary.rdlc"
        RDLCreportview.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        RDLCreportview.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        ds.Dispose()
        ds = Nothing
        RDLCreportview.ShowDialog()
        RDLCreportview.Dispose()
        Conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, it's not possible due the complexity of the final table. I see one solution in your situation. You need to change the query. Instead of using the table directly, you need to modify the query to give you want you need and then populate in the report. Here is how I would write that (`TESTED`):

```
CREATE TABLE #tempSO
(
    course varchar(10),
    adcat varchar(10),
    sub1 varchar(10),
    sub2 varchar(10),
    sub3 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #tempSO VALUES ('Ba1', 'Reg', 'HL','Hlit', 'His')
INSERT INTO #tempSO VALUES ('Ba1', 'Reg', 'EL','Hlit', 'HS')
INSERT INTO #tempSO VALUES ('Ba1', 'Pri', 'HL','His', 'Hlit')
INSERT INTO #tempSO VALUES ('Ba1', 'Reg', 'SL','Socio', 'Slit')

SELECT course, sub, 
       sum([Reg]) AS Reg, sum([Pri]) AS Pri

FROM (
    SELECT course, sub1 AS sub, adcat
    FROM #tempSO

    UNION ALL

    SELECT course, sub2 AS sub, adcat
    FROM #tempSO

    UNION ALL

    SELECT course, sub3 AS sub, adcat
    FROM #tempSO
) SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(adcat) for adcat IN ([Reg], [Pri])
) PivotTable
GROUP BY course, sub
```

You can also create a view in the database using the query above. Then call that view in the report instead of the original table. In this case, you can reuse the view in different reports the you need it.

**Update** (based on your update):

Here is how your `sqlQry` variable will look like now:

```
 sqlQRY = "SELECT course, sub, sum([Reg]) AS Reg, sum([Pri]) AS Pri FROM( " _
        & "SELECT course, sub1 AS sub, adcat FROM tblstudetail UNION ALL " _
        & "SELECT course, sub2 AS sub, adcat FROM tblstudetail UNION ALL " _
        & "SELECT course, sub3 AS sub, adcat FROM tblstudetail) SourceTable " _
        & "PIVOT (COUNT(adcat) for adcat IN ([Reg], [Pri])) PivotTable GROUP BY course, sub " _
        & "where [session] = '2015' " _
        & "AND [course] = 'B.A. I' " _
        & "AND [ADstatus] LIKE 'OK'"
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. but how can i call the view in my application

Comment: The same way you call your table previously. The view is your data source for report.

Comment: i edited my question where i m showing how i call my report earlier. is it the same way i should call again or else

Comment: Yes. `sqlQRY` parameter is what you need to modify. Replace it with my select statement.

Comment: sir please help. i am trying from last two days can u please give me some idea. how to modify my sqlQRY.

Comment: but it is showing error:
A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source'DataSet1’
kindly help

Comment: You aren't attaching datasource to the report. You're missing this line: `RDLCreportview.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sReportDataSource)`.

Comment: thanks man its working... but only one problem it is showing one blank column like course= empty reg=0 pri= 0.kindly help for last

Comment: Good. Please mark it as answered if I have been helpful. Thank you.